# print n users and their value using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl require your help to build a logic.

I have some let say 10 files in a directory, each file has some data like below. Each file contain lines depends upon the number of users setting. For example if 4 users are there then 4 lines will get printed from the server.

```
1405075666889,4044,SOA_breade,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,623,4044
1405075666889,4041,SOA_breade,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,623,4041
1405075666889,4043,SOA_breade,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,623,4043
1405075666889,4045,SOA_breade,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,623,4044
```

I want to some piece of logic that should create single file in a output directory and that file should contain 10 lines

```
Min_Value, Max_Value, Avg_Value, User1, User2, User3......User4
```

and their corresponding values from second line in this case corresponding values are coming from second column.

```
Min_Value, Max_Value, Avg_Value, User1, User2, User3......User4
4.041,4.045,4.044,4.041,4.043,4.045
.
.
.
.
.
```

10th file data

Here is my code... It is working however **I am not getting how to print user1, user2... in sequence and its corresponding values**

```
my @soaTime;
my @soaminTime;
my @soamaxTime;
my @soaavgTime;
my $soadir = $Json_Time;
foreach my $inputfile (glob("$soadir/*Overview*.txt")) {
    open(INFILE, $inputfile) or die("Could not open  file.");
    foreach my $line (<INFILE>)  {

        my @values = split(',', $line); # parse the file
        my $time_ms = $values[1]/1000;
        push (@soaTime, $time_ms);
    }

    my $min = min @soaTime;
    push (@soaminTime, $min);
    print $soaminTime[0];
    my $max = max @soaTime;
    push (@soamaxTime, $max);
    sub mean { return @_ ? sum(@_) / @_ : 0 };
    #print mean(@soaTime);
    push (@soaavgTime, mean());
    close(INFILE);
}

my $outputfile = $report_path."abc.txt";
open (OUTFILE, ">$outputfile");
print OUTFILE ("Min_Value,Max_Value,User1,User2,User3,User4"."\n"); # Prining the data
for (my $count = 0; $count <= $#soaTC; $count++) {
    print     OUTFILE("$soaminTime[0],$soamaxTime[0],$soaTime[0],$soaTime[1],$soaTime[2],$soaTime[3]"."\n"     );           #Prining the data
}
close(OUTFILE);
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]. StackOverflow is not a service where you post a problem and other people solve it for you.  You are expected to do the work yourself and then, when you encounter a problem, ask a specific question about code _you_ wrote.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for your valuable comment. I have add my code for reference

Comment: Thanks for showing your code but you have not told us the issue your code has. What's the problem with the code you have written? Does it run? Does it produce a file in the wrong format? Does it produce a file with no output? Its great you have listed the code and also your input and expected output but please tell us the specific issue you have with your code.

Comment: Can you fill us in on what your data represents? Is this your entire program? What's `$Json_time? Do you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` on your program?

Answer (score 0):

is it?

```
use strict;
use List::Util qw( min max );
my $Json_Time="./test";
my $report_path="./out/";
my @soaTime;
my @soaminTime;
my @soamaxTime;
my @soaavgTime;
my @users;
my $maxusers;
my $soadir = $Json_Time;
foreach my $inputfile (glob("$soadir/*Overview*.txt")) {
    open(INFILE, $inputfile) or die("Could not open  file.");
    my $i=0;
    my @m_users;
    my @m_soaTime;
    foreach my $line (<INFILE>)  {
        my @values = split(',', $line); # parse the file
        my $time_ms = $values[1]/1000;
        push (@m_soaTime, $time_ms);
        $i++;
        push(@m_users, "User".$i);
    }
    push(@soaTime,\@m_soaTime);
    if ($maxusers<$#m_users) {
        @users=@m_users;
        $maxusers=$#m_users;
    }
    my $min = min(@m_soaTime);
    push (@soaminTime, $min);
    my $max =max(@m_soaTime);
    push (@soamaxTime, $max);
    sub mean { return @_ ? sum(@_) / @_ : 0 };
    push (@soaavgTime, mean());
    close(INFILE);

}
my $outputfile = $report_path."abc.txt";
open (OUTFILE, ">$outputfile");
print OUTFILE "Min_Value,Max_Value,Avg_Value,".join(',',@users)."\n"; # Prining the data
for (my $count = 0; $count <= $#soaavgTime; $count++) {
    print OUTFILE $soaminTime[$count].","
        .$soamaxTime[$count].","
        .$soaavgTime[$count].","
        .join(',',@{$soaTime[$count]})
        ."\n";           #Prining the data
}
close(OUTFILE);
```